# How to get angle from simultaneous trig equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have following equations to get $\theta$ in terms of $a_1,...,a_4$
$$ a_1cos(\theta)^3 + a_2cos(\theta)^2sin(\theta) + a_3cos(\theta)sin(\theta)^2 + a_4sin(\theta)^3 = 0\\
a_4cos(\theta)^3 - a_3cos(\theta)^2sin(\theta) + a_2cos(\theta)sin(\theta)^2 - a_1sin(\theta)^3 = 0\\
a_2cos(\theta)^3 - a_3sin(\theta)^3 - 3a_1cos(\theta)^2sin(\theta) - 2a_2cos(\theta)sin(\theta)^2 + 2a_3cos(\theta)^2sin(\theta) + 3a_4cos(\theta)sin(\theta)^2 = 0 $$

I can simplify this by setting $y = \sin(\theta), x = \cos(\theta)$

$$ x^2 + y^2 = 1\\
a_1x^3 + a_2x^2y + a_3xy^2 + a_4y^3 = 0\\
a_4x^3 - a_3x^2y + a_2xy^2 - a_1y^3 = 0\\
a_2x^3  + (2a_3 - 3a_1)x^2y +  (3a_4- 2a_2)xy^2  - a_3y^3= 0 $$

Then I can (1) solve the first and the second equations to get $y$ in terms of $a_1,...,a4,x$, 
$$ y^2 = 1 - x^2\\a_1x^3+a_3x(1-x^2)+(a_4(1-x^2)+a_2x^2)y = 0 \\
=> y = -\frac{a_1x^3+a_3x(1-x^2)}{a_4(1-x^2)+a_2x^2}
$$
(2) solve the third one to get $x$ in terms of  $a_1,...,a_4$, 
$$
(a_4(1-x^2)+a_2x^2)(a_4x^3+a_2x(1-x^2))+\\
(a_1(1-x^2)+a_3x^2)(a_1x^3+a_3x(1-x^2))=0\\
⇒  (a_4+(a_2-a_4)x^2)(a_2-(a_2-a_4)x^2)+ \\
 (a_1+(a_3-a_1)x^2)(a_3-(a_3-a_1)x^2)=0\\
 ⇒ (a_4+b_2x^2)(a_2-b_2x^2)+(a_1+b_1x^2)(a_3-b_1x^2)=0\\
 ⇒   a_2a_4+a_1a_3+(b_2^2+b_1^2)x^2(1-x^2)
 =0\\
 ⇒  x = -\sqrt{\frac{d + \sqrt{(d(4c + d))}}{2d}},\\
\sqrt{\frac{d - \sqrt{(d(4c + d))}}{2d}},\\
-\sqrt{\frac{d - \sqrt{(d(4c + d))}}{2d}}, or\\
\sqrt{\frac{d + \sqrt{(d(4c + d))}}{2d}},\\
$$
where $b_1=a_3-a_1, b_2 = a_2-a_4, c=a_2a_4+a_1a_3, d=b_2^2+b_1^2,$ and (3) check the possible solutions with the last equation to finally find $\theta = cos^{-1}(x)$.

But I wonder if this is the right way. Is there any other trick I couldn't see?

Comment: Add the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

$$a_1x^3 + a_2x^2y + a_3xy^2 + a_4y^3 = 0\\
a_4x^3 - a_3x^2y + a_2xy^2 - a_1y^3 = 0\\
a_2x^3  + (2a_3 - 3a_1)x^2y +  (3a_4- 2a_2)xy^2  - a_3y^3= 0$$

---

Using $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ reduce the powers of $y$, i.e. substitute for $y^2$

$$a_1x^3 + a_2x^2y + a_3x(1-x^2) + a_4(1-x^2)y = 0\\
a_4x^3 - a_3x^2y + a_2x(1-x^2) - a_1(1-x^2)y = 0\\
a_2x^3  + (2a_3 - 3a_1)x^2y +  (3a_4- 2a_2)x(1-x^2)  - a_3(1-x^2)y= 0$$

---

Isolate y:

$$y(a_2x^2  + a_4(1-x^2)) + a_1x^3  + a_3x(1-x^2) = 0\\
-y(a_3x^2 + a_1(1-x^2)) + a_4x^3  a_2x(1-x^2)  = 0\\
y((2a_3 - 3a_1)x^2  - a_3(1-x^2)) + a_2x^3   +  (3a_4- 2a_2)x(1-x^2) = 0$$

---

Use this trick to eliminate $y$:

$$ yc_1 + R_1 = 0, \pm yc_2 + R_2 = 0 \rightarrow c_2R_1 \mp c_1R_2 = 0$$

---

First and second equations:

$$(a_3x^2 + a_1(1-x^2))(a_1x^3  + a_3x(1-x^2)) + (a_2x^2  + a_4(1-x^2))(a_4x^3  a_2x(1-x^2))  = 0$$

First and third equations:

$$((2a_3 - 3a_1)x^2  - a_3(1-x^2))(a_1x^3  + a_3x(1-x^2)) -  
(a_2x^2  + a_4(1-x^2))(a_2x^3 + (3a_4- 2a_2)x(1-x^2)) = 0$$

---

Resulting in two polynomials in $x$.

Solve each and test in the other equation. Note $|x| = |\cos(\theta)| \le 1$.